# how to correctly place the text labels in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have drawn scatter for a data set which describes doping in professional bicycle racing,while my plotting dots are currently oriented,iam failing to label them correctly right beside the dots,labels appear for few dots only,any hint on where iam doing wrong while labeling the dots will be useful

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/renx777/pen/ZXgBYE?editors=0010)

```
// get data from the server
$.getJSON(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json",
  function(x) {
    var margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = x;
    var rankings = [];
    var values = [];

    //populate rankings and values variable with data
    for (var i in data) {
      rankings.push(data[i]["Place"]);
      values.push(data[i]["Seconds"] - 2210);
    }

    //function to format label on x-axis
    var formatMinutes = function(d) {
      var hours = Math.floor(d / 3600),
          minutes = Math.floor((d - hours * 3600) / 60),
          seconds = d - minutes * 60;
      var output = seconds + "s";
      if (minutes) {
        output = minutes + "m " + output;
      }
      if (hours) {
        output = hours + "h " + output;
      }
      return output;
    };

    var x = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.max(values), 0])
    .range([0, width - 300]);

    var xAxis = d3
    .axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(6)
    .tickFormat(formatMinutes);

    //define yscale
    var y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([d3.max(rankings), 0]);

    var yaxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);

    //define chart div
    var chart = d3
    .select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + 500 + "," + margin.top + 100 + ")"
    );

    //     draw x axis
    svg
      .append("g")
      .call(xAxis)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    // draw yaxis
    svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yaxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em");

    // draw dots on the graph
    svg
      .selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.Doping.length == 0) {
        return "black";
      } else {
        return "red";
      }
    })
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.Seconds - 2210);
    })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.Place);
    });

    //add text labels to the dots
    svg
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "left")
      .attr("x", function(d) {

      return x(d.Seconds - 2210);
    })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.Place);
    })
      .text(function(d) {
      return d.Name;
    })
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,+4)");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it but few minor changes would help get the desired result.

1. I think you mean to use "y" and not "yscale" (yscale is not defined)
2. It's always better to use a `<g>` and wrap the dots within it. Here's a snippet of that:
   `svg.append("g").classed('dots', true);`
3. Now append all the dots and texts to the  (group) i.e.

   ```
   svg.select('g.dots').selectAll(".dot").data(data).enter().....

   svg.select('g.dots').selectAll("text").data(data).enter()....
   ```
4. That's it. Here's a [DEMO](https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/RLXLwj?editors=0010). You can now apply font-styles to the texts as per the requirement.

Hope this helps. :)